# Proof of complex inequality: $|z-1|\le|\sqrt{z^2-1}|\le|z+1|$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Hello I'm trying to prove some inequality of complex number but I'm getting stuck: the inequality is as follows:

> $$|z-1|\le|\sqrt{z^2-1}|\le|z+1|\quad\mbox{ for } \operatorname{Re}(z)>0$$

Now what I do is as follow:

1. $|z-1|^2=|z|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(z)+1 \implies |z-1|^2\le|z|^2+1 $ (and now I'm stuck).
2. $|z+1|^2=|z|^2+2\operatorname{Re}(z)+1 \implies |z+1|^2\ge|z|^2+1 $ (and now I'm stuck)

I feel I'm close but I lack the transition from what I get to where in need to go.

Hope someone will be able to enlighten me in that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $|z-1|^2=|z|^2-2Re(z)+1$ and $|z+1|^2=|z|^2+2Re(z)+1$; and because $Re(z)\gt0$, it can be directly stated that $|z-1|^2\lt|z+1|^2$, whence $|z-1|\lt|z+1|$.

If $w$ is a square root of $z^2-1$, the required inequality is equivalent to:
$$
|z-1|^2\le|w|^2\le|z+1|^2.
$$
Because $|w|^2 = |w^2| = |z^2 - 1| = |(z - 1)(z + 1)|$, this inequality is in turn equivalent to:
$$
|z-1|^2\le|z-1||z+1|\le|z+1|^2.
$$

$\rightarrow (\sqrt{(z-1)(z^*-1)})^2\le\sqrt{(z-1)(z^*-1)}\sqrt{(z+1)(z^*+1)}\le(\sqrt{(z+1)(z^*+1)})^2$

Now because $Re(z)\gt0$ and the fact that $|z-1|\lt|z+1|$ which means $\sqrt{(z-1)(z^*-1)}\lt\sqrt{(z+1)(z^*+1)}$ we can directly state that the inequality holds.

side note, if $z=1$ then $w=0$ and the inequality also holds {$0\le0\le2$}.

Comment: That's basically right, or at least it's not wrong! But it's more complicated than it needs to be. You had already arrived at the answer by your fourth paragraph. There was no need to expand $|z \pm 1|^2$ as $(z \pm 1)(z^* \pm 1)$, which only leads to hard-to-read complications. Also your definition of $w$ is verbose and unclear, and $|z + 1|$ should be $|z + 1|^2$. You should write $|w|^2 = |w^2|$ explicitly. Your logical implication signs go in the wrong direction, making the logic unclear. The fourth paragraph unnecessarily repeats the end of the third. A hint to simplify: "geometric mean".

Comment: I'm not following your point. would you be able to edit in order for me to see where i was wrong (or not accurate); also what do you mean in "geometric mean" how it can added to the formulated explanation. would appreciate some more clarifications.

Comment: I have made some minor changes (minor in my opinion, anyway!) to your first four paragraphs, turning them into three. You can view the changes in detail in the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2982623/revisions) of the question - and of course make any further changes you like, including reversing any overly drastic changes I may have made! I have left one final act of major surgery up to you. :)

Comment: Incidentally, at least one of the criticisms in my first comment was unfair: your fourth paragraph didn't merely repeat the end of your third. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually on the way to an answer. What confused me about the question, and may be confusing you as well, is the use of the square root symbol, when the square root of a complex number is not uniquely defined.

But if $w$ is *either* of the two square roots of $z^2 - 1$ (they are "both" equal to $0$ if $z = 1$, of course!), then $w^2 = z^2 - 1 = (z - 1)(z + 1)$, therefore $|w|^2 = |w^2| = |z - 1||z + 1|$; and what we have to prove is $|z - 1| \leqslant |w| \leqslant |z + 1|$.

But you have proved $|z - 1| \leqslant |z + 1|$ (because $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geqslant 0$ - strict inequality not needed). Therefore ...?

Comment: exactly, this is why I feel like a dead end; i mean i did prove the last inequality that appear in your answer but i don't know how to state properly the middle statement of the inequality stated in the title of the question.
maybe you have some insight about that, it will be very helpful;
Thanks

Comment: I think the fault lies in the question rather than in you. Perhaps I've misunderstood, but I think there is nothing you or anyone else can do other than rewrite the question along the lines I have suggested. I don't think I have ever seen an expression like $\sqrt{z^2 - 1}$, with $z$ complex, written in such a bald way before. Is there perhaps some context that sheds light? (I'm not very hopeful!)

Comment: No unfortunately, i asked the professor if there might be some mistake in the question or is there some data that is missing that is crucial for solving that inequality.
As soon as ill have some insight in the matter ill share it.

Comment: You shouldn't lose heart, because, as I tried to show in my answer (left unfinished, so you still have something to do), it is possible to solve the problem in spite of its ambiguous statement. There are only two square roots (only one, if $z = 1$), and it doesn't matter which of them you choose.

Comment: I see, i think i got your point.
w^2=z^2-1 -> so the inequality is |z-1|<=|w|<=|z+1|
now we showed that |z-1|<=|z+1| => |z-1|^2<=|z+1|^2 for Re(z)>0; so the total inequality squared is becoming:
(sqrt((z-1)(z*-1)))^2<= sqrt((z-1)(z*-1))sqrt((z+1)(z*+1))<= (sqrt((z+1)(z*+1)))^2 and now its directly imply the inequality is true.
is that what you aimed to?

Comment: I *think* that's along the right lines, although it is hard to read without MathJax formatting! You could try writing it up as an answer to your own question, and I (and perhaps others) will comment. If it's OK (with or without further edting ... oops ... editing), you can accept your own answer to your own question (although I vaguely recall you might have to wait a day or so before doing so). You can use formatting in comments, by the way.